# cant run my sendGrid Node.js Code

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using PostMan to post the request but cant recieve email on the other end + there are no errors that could point to any problem,
Every tutorial has the same code and I cant get it to run....

Kindly respond soon as this has been a real pain...

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const SENDGRID_API_KEY ='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';
const SENDGRID_SENDER = 'fazalkarim1994@gmail.com';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/fazal', (request, response) => {
    var sg = require('sendgrid')(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    var request = sg.emptyRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v3/mail/send',
    body: {
        personalizations: [
          {
              to: [
                    {
                        email: 'bsef13m026@pucit.edu.pk',
                    },
                  ],
              subject: 'Hello World from the SendGrid Node.js Library!',
          },
                           ],
        from: {
            email: 'fazalkarim1994@gmail.com',
              },
        content: [
                   {
                      type: 'text/plain',
                      value: 'Hello, Email!',
                   },
                ],
        },
});

//With promise 
    sg.API(request).then(response => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.body);
            console.log(response.headers);
}).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.statusCode);
});

//With callback 
sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error response received');
    }
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body);
    console.log(response.headers);
});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: if that's your real api key and email, then it's probably not wise to be including it your question

Comment: it is just a learning task so i think no much of problem